# How to decide on a color pallet for an application?

Tags: color, color-theory, style-guide

How does one decide which color pallet to associate with an application? How do you make color communicate tone of app?

Deciding one color is easy: say gray for serious enterprise theme. But how about about the rest of the colors in the pallet?

I have seen people picking up a picture and extracting colors from it to complete a pallet. Is this good practice?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to learn the color theory first. Then only you will be able to know which app need what kind of colors. Colors matters alot in any part of designing not only in app designing but also in icon/web/print etc... designs as well. Colors provide the asthetic value to the design. Get into the core of colors.

I am adding some links below from which you can get idea about the color themes:

[Link1](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/01/underestimated-power-color-mobile-app-design/)
[Link 2](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-color-schemes-in-mobile-ui-design/)
[Link 3](http://sourcebits.com/app-development-design-blog/10-essential-color-tips-app-design/)

Hope these links will help you.

Comment: Quite right. A grounding in proper colour theory is essentially and should not be skipped.

Comment: @mayersdesign yeah exactly :)